# Maximum element in a stack java

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, stack, max

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/maximum-element

ques is to perform three queries 1-for adding elment to stack 2-for poping element 3-for printing max element
link is posted above
iam not able to get output for 6-7 cases on hackerrank

```
    int n,i;int in1,in2;
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    n=sc.nextInt();
    Stack<Integer> st=new Stack<Integer>();//stack for elements
    Stack<Integer> stmax=new Stack<Integer>(); // stack for storing maximum
        for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
        in1=sc.nextInt();
        if(in1==1)
            {
                     in2=sc.nextInt();
                     if(st.size()==0)
                       {

                              stmax.push(in2);
                              st.push(in2);
                       }
                     else
                         {
                              if(in2>=stmax.peek())
                                  {

                              stmax.push(in2);
                              }
                               st.push(in2);

                          }    
        }
        if(in1==2)
            {
            if(st.peek()==stmax.peek())
                stmax.pop();
            st.pop();

        }
        if(in1==3)
            {
            System.out.println(stmax.peek());
        }

        }
```

Comment: What does "not able to get the output" mean?

Comment: @abhinav please be specific and brief when asking questions...

Comment: Comment your code, and have your IDE format it prior to posting. Use a spelling Checker.

Comment: i am not able to pass 7 test cases on hackerrank. link is  posted above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is correct but instead of `if(st.peek()==stmax.peek())` use `if(st.peek().equals(stmax.peek()))` this will make your code pass all the test cases

Comment: thanks for the ans! it is now working. but can you explain your solution.

Comment: your stacks use Integers and Integers are objects the same as String so == actually means reference equality not value equality and you need value equality